# How to delete files and subdirectories from folder but not that folder itself?

Tags: windows, command-line

What commands can I use (from the command prompt) to delete all files and all subdirectories from a folder, but not delete the folder itself? Basically at the end of the delete, there should be an empty folder.

Comment: i know rmdir /s  but it deleting that folder itself also

Comment: window command prompt

Answer (score 10):

```
cd <foldername>
del *.*
```

will delete the files.  You'll need to do

```
rmdir /s <subfolder>
```

for each subfolder.

**Update**

Try this in a batch file:

```
@echo off
cd "%1"
del *.* /y
for /d %%i in (*) do rmdir /s /q "%%i"
```

Call it something like EmptyDir.bat.  Then you can type:

```
emptydir <dirname>
```

and it will delete the files and folder in that folder, but leave the folder there.

Comment: can't we do some generic coding for this

Comment: See update for example script

Comment: It's been a long time since you needed `*.*` to indicate all files. Just `*` works fine (Windows has a concession where `*.*` matches all files, even those without dots in the middle).

Comment: @Greg Hewgill:  True.  Force of habit.

Answer (score 0):

`$> wipe.bat myExampleFolder`

```
rmdir /s $1
mkdir $1
```

With this solution, you may specify relative to current folder or even absolute paths.

Be sure to be aware of dangers. I.e. if the folder you chose to delete does not exists. (That is, why for example `cd <targetdir>| del *.*` can be quite dangerous... If you look for other solutions, current-directory-restore might be your friend:

```
@set OLDDIR=%CD%
cd $1
echo do stuff...
@cd /d %OLDDIR%
```